# Examine convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{\ln{\frac{n+1}{n}}} \right) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need some help with following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{\ln{\frac{n+1}{n}}} \right)$$

I have no idea how I should modify or compare it with something else.

Comment: At first sight, the second term is asymptotic to $1/\sqrt n$ and there is cancellation. The next term in the Taylor's development will be of order $n^{-3/2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln\frac{n+1}{n}=\frac1n\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})\right)$$
and so
$$\sqrt{\ln\frac{n+1}{n}}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac1{4n}+O(n^{-2})\right).$$
Then
$$\frac1{\sqrt n}-\sqrt{\ln\frac{n+1}{n}}=\frac1{4n^{3/2}}+O(n^{-5/2}).$$

Comment: yes of course, I see now thanks

Answer (score 2):

Also, [from](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615890?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
$$\frac{x}{1+x}\leq \ln{(1+x)}\leq x, \forall x>-1$$
we have 
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n+1}}\leq \sqrt{\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
or
$$0\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$
where 
$$0\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n}}< \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}< \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n^3}}$$
As a result
$$0\leq\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{\ln{\frac{n+1}{n}}} \right)<
\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
which [converges, since $\frac{3}{2}>1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: Nice bracketing of the logarithm.